# Blender only sticks with one speaker?

Tags: audio

Sometimes when I animate in blender I work with audio (mainly lip syncing characters), and I like to share it with people around me, so I unplug the headphones so they can hear it, but blender doesn't output with the default laptop speakers. I have to reload blender to get the speakers to output, but when I plug the headphones back in it keeps outputting through the speakers. It seems like blender only outputs the speaker that's available, but keeps it for the entire session. Is there a way I can change this? Here's some info on my computer:

OS: Windows 10 Home

Computer: Inspiron 3521 (Dell laptop)

RAM: 4GB RAM, 3.87 GB usable

Processor: Intel Core i3-3227U CPU @ 1.90GHz

As for the speakers, one is a Turtle Beach PX22 headset, the other is a built in Realtek (High Definition Audio). I also use Blender 2.74. Hope you can help!

Comment: does that happen using other apps as well?

Comment: @cegaton No, it only does it for Blender. This is the first time I've noticed it as well.